# Deserialize only some fields of JSON objects array (Java)

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

Given this JSON response I get from an website :

```
{
  "Items":
   [
    { "Name":"Apple", "Price":12.3, "Quantity":30 },
    { "Name":"Grape", "Price":3.21, "Quantity":60 }
   ],
   "Date":"21/11/2010"
}
```

How could i deserialize this JSON, splitting it in an array called Fruits, containing only name and quantity ? I don't care about date field or other fields like price.

My class should look like:

```
class Fruit{
   String name;
   String quantity;
}
```

And this is the array:

```
Fruit myfruits[] = new Fruit [this number depends on  JSON response I get]
```

How could I achive this ?
I've tried to give my best explanation, if it is still not clear, feel free to ask.

P.S: btw, the real JSON response has many more fields

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations)

Comment: wasn't the answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore the fields you don't wont.

Each serialization frameworks does it in different ways.

In some you can add annotations to you `POJO`, or set it with the serializer instance

Using `Gson`:

[Gson ignore json field and deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635226/gson-ignore-json-field-and-deserialize)

Using `Jackson`:

[Ignoring new fields on JSON objects using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson)