# JSON To ArrayList<CustomObject> With GSON While Ignoring Certain Fields

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

I am looking to create an `ArrayList` of custom objects from a JSON feed using GSON. My current approach works fine for a single JSON object holding an array, but now I need to parse a more complex JSON object. The first JSON feed looked like this:

```
{"data": 
    {"item_id": "1", "element": "element1"}
    {"item_id": "2", "element": "element2"}
    {"item_id": "3", "element": "element3"}
    ...
}
```

My method for extracting each item was using a simple custom object and parsing the JSON into an `ArrayList` of these objects.

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

Type listType = new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<CustomObject>>>(){}.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Map<String, ArrayList<CustomObject>> tree = gson.fromJson(input, listType);
ArrayList<CustomObject> = tree.get("data");
```

The current JSON object looks like this:

```
{"rate_limit": 1, "api_version": "1.2", "generated_on": "2015-11-05T19:34:06+00:00", "data": [
    {"collection": [
        {"item_id": "1", "time": "2015-11-05T14:40:55-05:00"},
        {"item_id": "2", "time": "2015-11-05T14:49:09-05:00"},
        {"item_id": "3", "time": "2015-11-05T14:51:55-05:00"}
    ], "collection_id": "1"},
    {"collection": [
        {"item_id": "1", "time": "2015-11-05T14:52:01-05:00"},
        {"item_id": "2", "time": "2015-11-05T14:49:09-05:00"},
        {"item_id": "3", "time": "2015-11-05T14:51:55-05:00"}
    ], "collection_id": "2"
]}
```

And I am having trouble parsing it because of the mixed types of data, some are numbers, strings and lastly arrays. I have a custom object built that takes an array of another custom object. This is the collection object:

```
public class CustomCollection {
    private String collection_id;
    private ArrayList<CustomItem> collection_items = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomCollection() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public CustomCollection(String id, ArrayList<CustomItem> items) {
        collection_id = id;
        collection_items = items;
    }

    public String getId() {
       return collection_id;
    }

    public ArrayList<CustomItem> getItems() {
        return collection_items;
    }
}
```

And this is the item object:

```
public class CustomItem {
    private String item_id;
    private String item_element;

    public CustomItem() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public CustomItem(String id, String element) {
        item_id = id;
        item_element = element;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public String getElement() {
        return item_element;
    }
}
```

I do not really care about obtaining the other elements (i.e. "rate_limit", "api_version", "generated_on"), I just want to pass the "data" element into an `ArrayList` of objects. But when I try something similar to my original method, the parser stops a the first object because it receives a number instead of an array. Resulting in an `IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line 1 column 17 path $.`. I would like to know how I can either get the parser to ignore the other elements, or how I can get each element separately using GSON.

**EDIT:** The proposed solution to my problem, found in [Ignore Fields When Parsing JSON to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423292/gson-ignore-json-fields-when-parsing-json-to-object), technically does solve my issue. But this seems like a lengthy process that is unnecessary in my case. I have found a much simpler solution to my problem, posted in my answer below. I am also unsure if this method would work well for the aforementioned question, considering there does not seem to be a way to get a `JsonObject` from a `JsonArray` by key name in GSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson - ignore json fields when parsing JSON to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423292/gson-ignore-json-fields-when-parsing-json-to-object)

Comment: use volley library instead of using standard network requests.

Comment: @RushiAyyappa This does not directly resolve my issue, but it helped with my app immeasurably. I did not know that the `Volley` library even existed, I feel like Google should make it more apparent, especially since (after doing some research) `AsyncTask` is considered pretty lousy. Anyway, I ended up using `RetroFit` from Square instead, I hear it is even faster and more lightweight than `Volley`. But thank you, this has put me on a much easier path.

Comment: welcome.Happy Coding!! @Bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found is to parse the data into a `com.google.gson.JsonObject`, then into a `JsonArray` by key name. I can then use this `JsonArray` as a parameter in `Gson.fromJson()` to extract the data into my `ArrayList` of custom objects.

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

JsonArray data = new JsonParser().parse(input).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("data");

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CustomCollection>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<CustomCollection> collection = new Gson().fromJson(data, listType);

input.close();
```

This method ignores all other JSON fields, only obtaining the one specified. It also takes the array of objects from within the "data" object and puts them into the `ArrayList` of custom objects within `CustomCollection`.